# Java - Date constructor accepts a Date String, But deprecated. Tried alternatives, but no luck

Tags: java, datetime, date

```
String temp_date="07/28/2011 11:06:37 AM";  
Date date = new Date(temp_date); //Depricated 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
String comp_date= sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(comp_date);
```

This works, But If I use something like this

```
String temp_date="07/28/2011 11:06:37 AM";  
try{  
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
    Date comp_date= sdf.parse(temp_date);
    System.out.println(comp_date);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This exception is thrown:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07/28/2011 11:06:37 AM"
```

Comment: Regarding the java.util.Date being deprecated, you might want to start taking a look at the abstract java.util.Calendar class and its direct implementation: java.util.GregorianCalendar

Comment: @Gevorg: `Calendar` is not very helpful when it comes to parsing/formatting dates from/to `String`. Regardless, I'd prefer Joda Time: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net.

Comment: @Balus - I heard of Beanutils of Apache commons for DateConversion. Incase you used beanutils - For the above case, how would it look like?

Comment: @BalusC: yes, for parsing/formatting then DateFormat is the answer. I was suggesting GC instead of the simple Date for datetime manipulation. I'm not familiar with Joda Time, I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your parsing pattern is wrong. It does not match the date string representation. The `MMM` denotes a 3-letter localized month abbreviation, while you have 2-digit month number in your actual date, you need `MM`. You've also slashes `/` as date/month/year separator and not `-`. For the AM/PM marker you also need an `a` afterwards so that the right `hh` can be parsed.

This should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

For an explanation of those patterns, read the [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

---

I believe that your concrete functional requirement is to convert the given date string as specified by the pattern `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a` into another date string format, as specified by the pattern `MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss`. In that case, you should then have two `SimpleDateFormat` instances, one which parses the string in the given pattern to a `Date` and another which formats the parsed `Date` to the given pattern. This should do what you want:

```
String inputDate = "07/28/2011 11:06:37 AM";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").parse(inputDate);
String outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
System.out.println(outputDate); // Jul-28-2011 11:06:37
```

Note that I changed `hh` in output to be `HH` because it would otherwise end up in 1-12 hour representation *without* an AM/PM marker. The `HH` represents it as 0-23 hour.

Answer (score 1):

The format you gave the SimpleDateFormat uses `-` between the month, date, and year.  Your string uses slashes.

Answer (score 1):

At first look, it looks as if your format string is wrong.

MMM  -- You specified this for the month, but you aren't passing a 3 char month.

Try MM and see if that helps.

Take a look at this for some additional date format information:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm