# Separating an array into Strings

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<String> stock_list = new ArrayList<String>();
stock_list.add("stock1");
stock_list.add("stock2");
```

I have this ArrayList, how do I separate into separate Strings so that I get
String a="stock1";
String b="stock2"?

Comment: Use the `List#get(int)` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Seperating an array into Strings

You are mistaken that it's an array. No, it is `ArrayList`.

ArrayList implements `List` and it  have a method [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) which takes index as a arg. Just get those strings back with index.

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

```
String a = stock_list.get(0);
String b = stock_list.get(1);
```

And you should consider to declare your ArrayList like

```
List<String> stock_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Which is called as [Programming with Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Suppose I have a date and time seperately.and I want to combine both of them to date.How to do it?Something like this 
`Time dateString=x14;
    Time dateString2=x16;
    Date dateString1=x15; 
Date d1 = new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString);`

Comment: @user3040563 No that date(string) is deprecated, look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876155/java-date-constructor-accepts-a-date-string-but-deprecated-tried-alternative

Answer (score 1):

just an alternative answer

```
String[] temp = new String[stock_list.size()];
stock_list.toArray(temp);
```

now `temp[0]` contains the first string and `temp[1]` contains the other.

Comment: You can do it in one step with `stock_list.toArray(new String[stock_list.size()]);`

Comment: Not intended as an optimization, just an observation. If you want to talk about readability, why not suggest `stockList`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("xxx");
Object[] array = list.toArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(" value = " + array[i].toString());
   }
```